# How do I make a histogram from a csv file which contains a single column of numbers in python?

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, histogram

I have a csv file (excel spreadsheet) of a column of roughly a million numbers. I want to make a histogram of this data with the frequency of the numbers on the y-axis and the number quantities on the x-axis. I know matplotlib can plot a histogram, but my main problem is converting the csv file from string to float since a string can't be graphed. This is what I have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

with open('D1.csv', 'rb') as data:
    rows = csv.reader(data, quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC) 
    floats = [[item for number, item in enumerate(row) if item and (1 <= number <= 12)] for row in rows]
plt.hist(floats, bins=50)
plt.title("histogram")
plt.xlabel("value")
plt.ylabel("frequency")
plt.show()
```

Comment: http://www.sscce.org/ What is the output you're getting from what you've tried, and how does it different from what you expect?

Comment: so you only have numbers in the file? Can you give an example of your input as your code does not seem to match your description

Comment: have you tries `float(item)`

Comment: I believe so, but I'm now trying to approach it in the more simplistic way using pandas that was posted by elyase. I just can't figure out what to put in place of 'column_you_want' in the code. Since it's excel I've tried 'A' , '1' , '0' and 'column_A', etc. I feel like its really obvious but I keep getting keyerror

Comment: I think the answer might be  slightly oversimplified, you will have to create the names and then access by the name/key for the column

Comment: I created a name for the column in excel and then referred to that name in python but that didn't work. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in one line with [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org):

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv('D1.csv', quoting=2)['column_you_want'].hist(bins=50)
```

Comment: If it is the first column in the excel document, what should I put in 'column you want'

Comment: I've tried 'A', '1', and '0' but its a keyword error. Thank you so much for simplifying this by the way. I'm new to programming in general as you can probably tell so this helps a lot

Comment: @DanielHodgkins, Try `df = pd.read_csv('D1.csv', quoting=2); print df.head()`. This way you will see what is the name of the column. To help you better paste the first rows of your csv in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Okay I finally got something to work with headings, titles, etc.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('D1.csv', quoting=2)
data.hist(bins=50)
plt.xlim([0,115000])
plt.title("Data")
plt.xlabel("Value")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.show()
```

My first problem was that matplotlib is necessary to actually show the graph. Also, I needed to set the action

```
pd.read_csv('D1.csv', quoting=2)
```

to data so I could plot the histogram of that action with

```
data.hist
```

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Panda's `read_csv` is very powerful, but if your csv file is simple (without headers, or NaNs or comments) you do not need Pandas, as you can use Numpy:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.loadtxt('D1.csv')
plt.hist(data, normed=True, bins='auto')
```

(In fact `loadtxt` can deal with some headers and comments, but `read_csv` is more versatile)